# Is a simple linear regression a mixed model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, terminology

This is a question about terminology... Is a simple linear regression model

$y_i = a + b x_i + r_i$ and $r_i\sim N(0,s)$

a mixed model where $a$ and $b$ are fixed effects, and the residual term $r_i$ is a random effect? In fact, $s$ in a conventional mixed model (e.g., including a random intercept) is treated as a random effect (Residual) in `lmer` output. In that sense, maybe the question applies to any normal distribution models such as t-tests.